# Support upto 300-500 users streaming at 500 kbps in 1 sq KM radius

Tags: wireless

I am from India and we are designing a video website for rural India. I am planning to setup WIFI broadcast tower within a village of approx 1 sq KM radius. I want to support 300 - 500 simultaneous users streaming at 500 kbps each.

I was thinking I would mount 3-4 TP LINK CPE210 antenna (http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/CPE210.html) on a single pole at the center of the village and have them wired to single SOHO router  that ultimately connect to an high speed broadband.

Do you think antennas like the CPE210 is good for such an scenario? Or in your expert opinion, what is the alternate design I could pursue?

Comment: Wi-Fi is bi-directional. The client computers have radios, too. What are you planning for them to be able to communicate at such distances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the antenna choice is the least of your problems.

500 users require 250 MB throughput.  I would be surprised if you can get that kind of Internet bandwidth in rural India.

Let's assume you can. Commercial Wifi routers can practically handle 40-50 simultaneous users.  If you have one on each channel, that's only 150 users.

Under ideal conditions, you can expect no more than 25 Mb throughput on each channel.  That's only 75Mb on all 3 channels.  And you will have far from ideal conditions.  Your clients will be farther away from the APs and will have to use lower data rates.  That will greatly reduce your throughput.

I would not expect a wireless client to work reliably more than 50-75 m from the access point under ideal conditions.

In short, if you were to set this up, you could only support a small percentage of your target users.  They would experience poor performance and would likely reject your solution as unusable.

Comment: Thanks Ron for the insight. We are going use a local caching server for the videos that we want to broadcast so internet bandwidth is not a concern. But the last mile b/w is important. Since I overestimated the power of a single wifi AP, the proposed solution will not work. What do you suggest i should go for? Considering that wiring may be a challenge, can I achieve desired throughout using a wireless mesh? Since most handsets in rural support only 2.4 GHz, i could use the 5 GHz band as a dedicated back haul and 2.4GHz for last mile. But then i will have to place the extension close enough

Comment: In theory, that's possible, but you will need many 2.4G access points, each with their own backhaul.  That's a lot of equipment.  The access points will need to be distributed through the coverage area, so you will need electricity.  I don't know how "rural" your area is.